# Django: problems with urlfields validation when overriding form validation

Tags: django, django-forms

I have some Form with two urlfields, both not required. The form is used to set the value of JSONField in a Model from these two urlfields (for user convenience), everything works fine. If a user enters something except an URL into url1 or url2, django shows validation error at the form "Enter a valid URL".

Now I want to make a user to input URL in ANY of these urlfields. I'm overriding clean method for that:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    url1 = forms.URLField(required=False)
    url2 = forms.URLField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        if not cleaned_data['url1'] and not cleaned_data['url2']:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("You should enter at least one URL"),
                code='no_urls'
            )
        return cleaned_data
```

It works, BUT there is a problem: if user enters some "non-URL" data into url1 or url2 and submits the form, Django raises KeyError with Exception Value: 'url1' (or 'url2') instead of showing a validation error at the form

What's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented in quite a few places - notably [the part about cross validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) -, `cleaned_data` only contains valid data - the fields that didn't validate wont show up here. You have to account for this one way or another - by testing for key existence or, [as shown in the cross-validation example snippet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), using `dict.get()`:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
    # boolean algebra 101: "not A and not B" => "not (A or B)"
    if not (cleaned_data.get('url1') or cleaned_data.get('url2')):
        raise ValidationError(
            _("You should enter at least one URL"),
            code='no_urls'
        )
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Thanks, Bruno! Got it, now it's fine. LOL @ algebra 101, really )))